# PHP isset not works on $this variable

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, isset, hmvc

I am trying to figure out why isset doesn't works on $this variable? I am using HMVC codeigniter and trying to check if module loaded successfully:

`$this->load->module('welcome');
var_dump(isset($this->welcome));
print_r($this->welcome);`

Result is:

```
bool(false) --- This is the result of isset. Below is result of var_dump
Welcome Object
(
    [autoload] => Array
        (
        )

    [load] => MY_Loader Object
        (
            [_module:protected] => welcome
            [_ci_plugins] => Array
                (
                )

            [_ci_cached_vars] => Array
                (
                )

            ... some other protected variables

            [controller] => Welcome Object
 *RECURSION*
        )

)
```

Why isset returns false?

Comment: try !empty() , it works for both, isset and empty.

Comment: used this code: `var_dump(empty($this->nonexisting));` returned true, even if it is not existed @AhmedSunny

Comment: take a look at [this ](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep checking CodeIgniter core files, I figured out there is a way to check it:

```
        if(!isset(Modules::$registry['welcome'])) { // check module loaded
            return jsonError(2);
        }

        // module loaded. Go ahead
```